# /dev/ttyACM0 lost after sleep - How to redetect / restart / rescan for ttyACM0?

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox, tty, serial-port

I posted [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1234055/269986) in Ubuntu, but was told that it didn't belong there since my installation is Mint 18.2 and needed to be moved here instead (I don't know how to move it).

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 based VM (Mint 18.2) which runs inside VirtualBox (6.2) on Windows 10.

```
eric@XMEANT ~ $ uname -a
Linux XMEANT 4.8.0-53-generic #56~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 16 01:18:56 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

On my Host, I've connected a ZWave USB antenna, which I've then mapped/attached to the VM.  When I first boot my VM, I can see that the USB device is properly detected as `/dev/ttyACM0`:

```
eric@XMEANT ~ $ dmesg | grep acm
[   18.593264] cdc_acm 2-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device

eric@XMEANT ~ $ ls /dev/ttyA*
/dev/ttyACM0
```

However, after I wake my Host wakes from sleep mode, I no longer see the device listed in my `/dev`.

```
eric@XMEANT ~ $ ls /dev/ttyA*
ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyA*': No such file or directory
```

Following hints I found on another [Superuser question](https://superuser.com/a/596911/130030), I tried the following:

```
eric@XMEANT ~ $ cat /proc/tty/drivers
/dev/tty             /dev/tty        5       0 system:/dev/tty
/dev/console         /dev/console    5       1 system:console
/dev/ptmx            /dev/ptmx       5       2 system
/dev/vc/0            /dev/vc/0       4       0 system:vtmaster
acm                  /dev/ttyACM   166 0-255 serial
ttyprintk            /dev/ttyprintk   5       3 console
max310x              /dev/ttyMAX   204 209-224 serial
serial               /dev/ttyS       4 64-111 serial
pty_slave            /dev/pts      136 0-1048575 pty:slave
pty_master           /dev/ptm      128 0-1048575 pty:master
unknown              /dev/tty        4 1-63 console

eric@XMEANT ~ $ lsmod | grep acm
cdc_acm                36864  0

eric@XMEANT ~ $ sudo modprobe -r cdc_acm
eric@XMEANT ~ $ sudo modprobe  cdc_acm
```

However, still no device found:

```
eric@XMEANT ~ $ ls /dev/ttyA*
ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyA*': No such file or directory
```

I've also tried to reset my USB drivers/modules, but they are built-into the kernel and don't know how to reload them independently.

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module ehci_pci is builtin.
modprobe: FATAL: Module ehci_hcd is builtin.
modprobe: FATAL: Module ohci_pci is builtin.
modprobe: FATAL: Module ohci_hcd is builtin.
Reloading USB modules...
```

I also saw this [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line) question, but not sure if it really applies as it is not detected as a USB device and rather as an ACM device.  I tried to restart the ModemManager, but that has had no impact either.

Finally, I've tried to unmap it from VirtualBox and remap it, but it made no difference.  The only way I've been able to figure out is to restart the VM.  But that is not really an effective solution as it can take several minutes to restart my VM and all services/etc.

Is there any other way I can force the VM to rescan/redetect the missing device or restart the subservice required to find it?